# Problem with custom payment module

Tags: module, magento-1, payment-methods

Unable to redirect to the third party site after clicking place order.. I think I am having problem with my controller and .phtml file. Help me with the controller and .phtml files.. How do I write corresponding controller and .phtml code for this one?

```
config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_ESewa>
            <version>1.0.0</version>    
        </MyModule_ESewa>   
    </modules>
    <global>
        <!-- declare helper class -->
        <helpers>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Helper</class>
            </esewa>
        </helpers>
        <!-- model -->
        <models>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Model</class>
            </esewa>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Block</class>
            </esewa>
        </blocks>
        <!-- end of model -->
    </global>   
    <!-- start start of declaretion of payment -->
    <!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
    <default>
    <!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
        <payment>
    <!-- 'newmodule' configuration group (fieldset) -->
            <esewa>
    <!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
                <active>0</active>
    <!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->          
                <model>esewa/standard</model>
                <!-- order status for new orders paid by this payment method -->
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <!-- set payment title to -->
                <title>Custom Payment</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>

            </esewa>        
        </payment>
    </default>
</config> 




system.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <sections>
                <!-- goto  Payment Section -->
                <payment>
                        <!-- now goto payment group -->
                        <groups>
                                <esewa  translate="label" module="esewa">
                                    <label>eSewa</label>
                                    <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                    <fields>
                                        <active translate="label">
                                            <label>Enable</label>
                                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>   
                                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website></show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </active>   
                                        <order_status translate="label">
                                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_newprocessing</source_model>
                                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </order_status>
                                        <title translate="label">
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </title>
                                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                                            <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </allowspecific>
                                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                                            <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>51</sort_order>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                                        </specificcountry>
                                        <sort_order translate="label">
                                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                                        </sort_order>

                                        <submit_url>
                                            <label>Gateway URL</label>
                                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                                    <sort_order>58</sort_order>
                                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </submit_url>

                                        <merchant_id>
                                            <label>Merchant ID</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>59</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </merchant_id>  
                                </fields>
                                </esewa>
                        </groups>   
                </payment>
        </sections>
</config>  



standard.php
<?php
class MyModule_ESewa_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'esewa';
    protected $_canAuthorize = true;
    protected $_isGateway = true;


    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
    {

        return Mage::getUrl('esewa/standard/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lot issue

### issue1:

You cannot declare `model and block,helpers types`  in Capital letter always change in lower case letter.so you need  change  **ESewa** to **esewa**

```
        <models><ESewa>..</ESewa></models>
        <helpers><ESewa>..</ESewa></helpers>
        <blocks><ESewa>..</ESewa></blocks>
```

modified config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_ESewa>
            <version>1.0.0</version>    
        </MyModule_ESewa>   
    </modules>
    <global>
        <!-- declare helper class -->
        <helpers>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Helper</class>
            </esewa>
        </helpers>
        <!-- model -->
        <models>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Model</class>
            </esewa>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <esewa>
                <class>MyModule_ESewa_Block</class>
            </esewa>
        </blocks>
        <!-- end of model -->
    </global>   
    <!-- start start of declaretion of payment -->
    <!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
    <default>
    <!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
        <payment>
    <!-- 'newmodule' configuration group (fieldset) -->
            <esewa>
    <!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
                <active>0</active>
    <!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->          
                <model>esewa/standard</model>
                <!-- order status for new orders paid by this payment method -->
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <!-- set payment title to -->
                <title>Custom Payment</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>

            </esewa>        
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

### Issue2:

system.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <sections>
                <!-- goto  Payment Section -->
                <payment>
                        <!-- now goto payment group -->
                        <groups>
                                <esewa  translate="label" module="esewa">
                                    <label>My Payment</label>
                                    <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                    <fields>
                                        <active translate="label">
                                            <label>Enable</label>
                                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>   
                                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website></show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </active>   
                                        <order_status translate="label">
                                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_newprocessing</source_model>
                                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </order_status>
                                        <title translate="label">
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                        </title>
                                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                                            <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </allowspecific>
                                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                                            <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>51</sort_order>
                                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                                        </specificcountry>
                                        <sort_order translate="label">
                                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                                        </sort_order>

                                        <submit_url>
                                            <label>Gateway URL</label>
                                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                                    <sort_order>58</sort_order>
                                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </submit_url>

                                        <merchant_id>
                                            <label>Merchant ID</label>
                                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                            <sort_order>59</sort_order>
                                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                        </merchant_id>  
                                </fields>
                                </esewa>
                        </groups>   
                </payment>
        </sections>
</config>
```

### ISSUE3:

**standard.php file should be Standard.php** and payment code `ESewa`  should be small letter `esewa` and code is

```
 <?php
class MyModule_ESewa_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'esewa';


public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    return Mage::getUrl('customcard/standard/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
}
}
?>
```

and `MyModule_ESewa_Model_standard`  to `MyModule_ESewa_Model_Standard`

**[Edit]:**

As you want say you want redirect to third party site.
According to 
you mo`dule after order place you will redirection  customcard/standard/redirect page`  and from `here you will redirect to third partly site.`

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours one.. When I now click on the Payment Methods tab inside System -> configuration -> Payment Methods, it leads to me blank page however I can see URL in address bar.. The url looks like: index.php/backend/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/20ec1cfa469f09de6331a2240f0210e3/ .. I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: as  you define system xml  so need acl permission.So to admin>System>permission>roles>Select admin role and save it and then clear cache by delete form your magneto dir/var/cache

Comment: did it! but still same problem, same blank page.. Can this issue happens if there is any problem on /app/etc/modules .xml file?

Comment: put  it...on qyestin

Comment: I have updated my question. See it

Comment: remove protected $_IsInitializeNeeded = ture;
    protected $_canUseInternal = false;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false; from standard.php

Comment: i have done some changes it works.... download module https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3lgl98ya247c91/MyModule_ESewa.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope you can surely help me.

Comment: are want to redirection to third party site after order place?

Comment: yes to the third party site

Comment: What you describe in issue 1 is best pratice but not a technical problem, so you can have uppercase letters in the model prefix :-)

Comment: @AmitBera to be more precise, When I click the place order, I need to redirect to http://www.whereshouldpay.com with the amount payable by the customer.. Help me. :)

Comment: fabian ,i want say block and model ,helper type need define  to  in small letter.

Comment: let me know ,if you have any issue

Comment: @AmitBera please see the question..high hopes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache and log out and login again.

Have you created the module file in app/etc/modules folder?
Go to system->configuration->advanced and see if your module is present in the list. If not, it should be present there before you can start seeing it in the admin.

Comment: It is present in system->configuration->advanced. But Whenever I tried to click the Payment Method inside System->configuration->Payment Methods,it will just show up the blank page however I can see a link in my address bar.

Comment: Try logging out and logging back in.